# How to get a finished iPhone 5 app to display AS IF in "compatibility mode" on iPad with retina display?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, compatibility

This is my first iPhone app (iPhone 5), and it's basically ready to submit to Apple except...

I'm stumped on how to get my app to display on the iPad like it would in compatibility mode if it had a 3.5 inch screen.  But it has a 4-inch screen, of course. It's an iPhone 5 app. And Apple has not yet provided a compatibility mode (that I am aware of) that will display the 4-inch screen properly in compatibility mode on the iPad.  Instead, compatibility mode distorts and cuts off the 4-inch layout and smushes it into a 3.5-inch compatibility mode box.

I have read all of the stackoverflow Q&A's that I could find, plus many other web pages, tried numerous approaches, but all solutions end up with my iPhone storyboard layout distorted on the iPad and/or nailed to the top left portion of the iPad screen, or both.

I've been banging my head on this for days.

I sure hope someone can help.

You know how 3.5-inch iphone apps look on the ipad in compatibility mode?  That is EXACTLY how I want my iPhone 5, 4-inch screen to look on the iPad, but with the 4-inch dimensions.  I do not want the app to occupy nearly all of the iPad screen. Just a box that looks like the iphone 5 app, hanging right there centered in the iPad screen. I don't have a problem with figuring out how to connect things to my view controllers, fwiw.

I don't know how to put this any more specifically.  If my question is unclear, perhaps someone could help me to restate it?  This is NOT a duplicate of other stackoverflow topics I have been able to find. But I'm willing to be corrected.

Hellllp! :-) Thanks in advance for any light you may be able to shed.  I'm hoping to avoid starting from scratch to create a usable iPad presentation for my iPhone 5 app.

Comment: Is there any reason at all why your design couldn't fit on 3.5-ich screen? With autoresizing, auto layout, scrollviews and all the tools you have, it shouldn't be too much work. There is no such thing as "4-inch compatibility" mode on iPad and will probably never be as it wouldn't fit the screen when scaled at 2x.

Comment: When you claim that your question is not a duplicate of other SO questions, it is helpful to provide links to the questions you have found and explain how your question differs from them.

Answer (score 0):

iPad doesn't work like that.  I believe the reason is that the 2x button would not scale properly for the 4 inch screen.

Either way, you need to make sure your app works well for the 3.5 inch screen anyway, this may be a good time to rethink some of the design of your app to make sure it works well in a 3.5 inch screen.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, all! I'll see what I can make of them. My design was specifically targeted for the 4-Inch screen and I use every bit of it well, I believe, from a UI design perspective. I was not anticipating having to redesign for a 3.5-inch version.  Just figured that working on design for the latest model would be OK. So this is a curve ball, from my perspective.  But it sounds like there's no way around it. Sorry to hear, but I guess I have no better choice until the 3.5-inch standard ages and falls away, probably in a year or two, I guess.

Thanks again for your help.